# Unable to consume WSDL in Mule 4

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am using anypoint studio 7.3.1 with Mule 4.1.x. trying to load the WSDL using Web Service Consumer. 
First I placed my WSDL file under src/main/resources of my project.
In Web Service Consumer, under connector configuration I selected my WSDL and at this point the mulesoft should automatically populate “Service”, “Port” and “Address”.
However that is not happening. I read somewhere that WSDL file needs to be exported to mule-artifact.json which I did, but still doesn’t work.

To make sure my WSDL is good, I was able to load the same WSDL in soapUI and was able to access the web service. 
What is it that I need to do to get this working? Is there any error log that tells what’s going on?   By the way, the endpoint is http so I know there is no cert issue.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was due to the xsd that was referred in the WSDL. Removed that and it worked